# What is the time complexity of array of struct and text file?

Tags: arrays, time, struct, complexity-theory

Here is the most important part of my program  ( the data is in a text file in 2 columns separated with comma (ex. 3,12)the first column value represents the weight and the second represents the profit ) this method fills the array of struct(struct has 2 fields weight and profit )  of size n from the data in the text file and then sorts the items accorrding to my comparision method as the following..

```
    static void Read(ref Items[] Item)
    {  
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\test1.txt");
        int i = 0;
        string[] word;
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)// n is the no of items that the user want to fill the array with
        {
            word = (lines[j].Split(','));
            word = (lines[j].Split(','));
            Item[i].Weight = float.Parse(word[0]);// Item is the name of array
            Item[i].Profit = float.Parse(word[1]);

            i++;
        }
   Array.sort(Item,mycomparision);
     }
```

So I'd like to compute the time and space complexity  of this method ( space complexity = input size + output size + any  data structure)..                                                               I really get confused what is the exact time and space complexity of the array of struct and the text file .Shall I consider the file size as an input  when I compute the space complexity or just the array ? Shall I  compute the time of opening the file and read the data to the array as a time complexity ??  and is my code so efficient or there is any better and more efficient code(i.e if the file contains 100,000 items but the user wants to read only 100 item is it ok to read all the item first " string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\test1.txt");" and then put only 100 to the array) ??          please guys don't hesitate to help me ^_^ .

Comment: Arrays don't have a time complexity, operations on the array do. Please post the code you're using.

Comment: @Lee I have edited my post with more details and code.. could you read it and help me, please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
The complexity of your program is O(n+2)

Since you have array of length n. you should need a max of n time units to find the element.

Then to get the two values of the struct you need another time units.
```

You will not need 2n because for each position of the array you have one struct.

From my analysis in general time complexity of array is O(n). You can refer the following links.

[time-complexity-algorithms1](http://www.sitepoint.com/time-complexity-algorithms/)

&

[time-complexity-algorithms2](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Comment: *Arrays don't have a time complexity, operations on the array do. Please post the code you're using. –  Lee*

Comment: @shekharsuman:: http://bigocheatsheet.com/ you can refer this link here you can see the time complexity of array as O(n).

Comment: Hey MAN, OP hasn't provided the operation to be performed on the array! You can't assume anything on behalf of OP and post answers. It is non-sense!!! I should have triple downvoted you,had it been possible!

Comment: @shekharsuman:: I have edited my post with more details and code .. pleaaaaase help me ..

Comment: @ Sridhar DD   I have edited my post with more details and code .. could you read it and  help me ,please??